# optional parameter sql function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

I have a function with optional param like this :

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_Foo] ( @P1 AS INT ,@p2 AS INT = 29 )
```

how to call it without passing the optional param?

```
select * from [dbo].[FN_Foo] (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the DEFAULT which is defined in your function

```
select *
from [dbo].[FN_Foo] (1, DEFAULT)
```

Comment: is a way to don`t pass anything?